# Using both basename and full path in find -exec

Tags: linux, find, filenames, rename

I'm having an adventure in the world of bash scripting with find today.

Say I'm looking to copy any png file in any subdirectory of /home/mine/Pictures to /home/mine/pngcoppies and rename it "copy[basename]"using find and -exec.  This would require me to use both the full path name and the basename in the same exec command.  My problem is that I don't know how to get the basename.  (See below)

```
find /home/mine -iname "*.png" -exec cp {} /home/mine/pngcoppies/copy{what_do_I_enter_here?} \;
```

**Note:** The above isn't actually what I'm doing, but it's a fundamental example of the issue, so a workaround using some other method to achieve the same ends wouldn't really apply here.  The question is fundamentally about find -exec and its use of basenames.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To see what is going on when you execute the find, just type `set -xv`

-x : Prints commands and their arguments as they are executed.

-v : Prints shell input lines as they are read.

Here is what I have :

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec echo {} \;
```

Gives the output:

```
./log.xml
./svnLog.xml
```

And when I try :

```
set -xv
find . -name "*.xml" -exec echo {} \;
```

I get :

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec echo {} \;
+ find . -name '*.xml' -exec echo '{}' ';'
./log.xml
./svnLog.xml
```

And then find execute echo passing the found filename instead of the litteral : `'{}'`

but when you add something to the `{}` like below :

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec echo something{} \;
+ find . -name '*.xml' -exec echo 'something{}' ';'
something{}
something{}
```

Here the echo is executed twice for the 2 xml files that I have and since there is no more `'{}'` is the parameter list of the exec, it is not going to be replaced. so we got the `echo 'something{}'` for each file found.

To deal with this, you can think about executing echo passing to it the filename as parameter like for example :

```
sh -xvc 'echo sothing/$0' filename
```

We already know what is `-x` and `-v`. `-c` is to get the command from the string after it (`man sh`)

so the result is :

```
sh -xvc 'echo somthing/$0' filename
+ sh -xvc 'echo somthing/$0' filename
echo somthing/$0
+ echo somthing/filename
sothing/filename
```

I used '`echo somthing/$0`' between ' ' so that $0 don't get expanded by the current shell. try it with " " and you will see the expantion of $0 ;)

So to get back to your 'problem', the find should be formatted as below:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec sh -xvc 'echo sothing/$0' {} \;
```

And we will get :

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec sh -xvc 'echo sothing/$0' {} \;
+ find . -name '*.xml' -exec sh -xvc 'echo sothing/$0' '{}' ';'
echo sothing/$0
+ echo sothing/./log.xml
sothing/./log.xml
echo sothing/$0
+ echo sothing/./svnLog.xml
sothing/./svnLog.xml
```

As we can see know, the find is going to execute the shell cammand `echo sothing/$0` passing to it `'{}'` (replaced by the filename found by find) so we get the desired `echo sothing/./log.xml`

`set +xv` to remove the verbose mode
and we can get :

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec sh -c 'echo "cp $0 someWhereElse/$0"' {} \;
cp ./log.xml someWhereElse/./log.xml
cp ./svnLog.xml someWhereElse/./svnLog.xml
```

so in your case , you have just to execute the copy in a sub shell (add `sh` or `bash` or you favorit shell after the exec) and let `find` pass the filename as parapeter to the it ;)

```
find /home/mine -iname "*.png" -exec sh -c 'cp $0 /home/mine/pngcoppies/copy/$0' {} \;
```

Hope this can help, and execuse me for my English.

Comment: That's great advise with the subshell! I just suggest quoting the `"$0"` to allow spaces.

Answer (score 20):

From man find:
"The -execdir primary is identical to the -exec primary with the exception that utility will be executed from the directory that holds the current file.  The filename substituted for the string ``{}'' is not qualified."

```
find /home/mine -iname "*.png" -execdir cp {} /home/mine/pngcoppies/copy{} \;
```

Comment: This is the one for me.

Comment: @Makkou's answer is good and an excellent explanation for one of the most maddening phenomenon in POSIX history, but this one makes the code a little bit more readable and solves the problem for a large class of cases. However, it's great to remember the more general solution for those edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this :

```
find  /home/mine -iname "*.png" -printf "%P\n " | xargs  -I % -n1 cp %  /home/mine/pngcoppies/copy%
```

Comment: I really like this approach, but I'm getting `find: -printf: unknown primary or operator` on OSX

Answer (score 0):

To get basename you use

```
basename $your_full_path
```

To get that path before the basename

```
dirname $your_full_path
```

Comment: Sorry to ask for spoonfeeding but how might I apply this to my instance of find?

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the first two answers

I was tailing everything in one directory into another directory with

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'tail -n 1000 $0 >../tail1000/$0.tail' {} \;
```

The first Answer gives

```
cp ./log.xml someWhereElse/./log.xml
```

or for my tail command

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'tail -n 1000 $0 >../tail1000/$0.tail' {} \;

tail -n 1000 ./filenane > ../tail1000/./filenane.tail
```

which surprisingly works but does not look like a nice path and I expect there are cases where a path/./morepath does something unexpected with some command.

Combining the answers gives

```
find . -type f -execdir sh -c 'tail -n 1000 $0 >../tail1000/$0.tail' {} \;
```

which executes

```
tail -n 1000 filenane > ../tail1000/filenane.tail
```

And looks much more likely to give the expected results.